# Error in SharePoint oAuth Authentication using Sharepoint Online CSOM and PnP in .net core

Tags: oauth, sharepoint-online

I am trying to make sharepoint authentication using oAuth(Azure AD App) using Sharepoint Online CSOM and PnP, but it gives error "The given key was not present in the dictionary.". I have created Azure AD App and added API permission for Sharepoint AllSite.FullControl in that app.

I am using trial sharepoint tenant.

Here is my code snippets:

```
ClientContext _sharepointContaxt = null;
string Username = [Username];
string Password = [Password];
string AppId="67b1845e-88b1-4e6c-b7db-7f1d3abe3b06";
Uri site = new Uri([Sharepoint_site_url]);                  
using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager("67b1845e-88b1-4e6c-b7db-7f1e3aae3a06"))
using (_sharepointContaxt = authenticationManager.GetContext(site, Username, SecurePassword(Password)))
{
   Web web = _sharepointContaxt.Web;
   _sharepointContaxt.Load(web);
   _sharepointContaxt.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same "The given key was not present in the dictionary." issue whenever I occasionally sent Post request to Azure AD in a for loop. I'm not sure if this failure scenario is as the same as yours.

One of my debug way is to check the `dictionary` and see which "given key" was lost. In `AuthenticationManager` class, there is a private method called `AcquireTokenAsync`. This method is to request Azure AD to return SPO accessing token, and save it as a Json format in variable `tokenResult`, and then use `GetProperty("access_token")` to get token.

If Azure AD did not return SPO token for some reason, `access_token` might not be available in the `tokenResult`, result in the error code you saw.

In this case, error message in `tokenResult` help you to see the reason why Azure AD did not return the token.

Comment: Spent an hour on this and your answer gave me what I needed! Thank you Evan.